# I forgot my passwork for wireless. How do I recover or change it for a Westell router

Tags: networking, password-recovery

Forgot my password for wireless.  How do I get it or change it.

Comment: Reset the router; check the manual on how to do that; then change the password to something you will remember

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific router but in general: if you didn't change the default password, it is usually in the user manual or on a sticker on the router.  If you have a direct (ethernet) connection on another computer, you can sometimes access the menus without a password and see what it is.  If all else fails, reset the router (typically a small hole in back marked "reset" where you insert a paperclip.  If you reset the router, you will need the manual to know the default password.

Comment: _you can sometimes access the menus without a password and see what it is._ And immediately upgrade the firmware so that's not possible, or replace it as this is a major security defect.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the router itself to reset the wireless-password. There should be some informations about that in the user-manual.

Also there is another way, if you know your router-password itself. Do open the Router-setup, you have to open the router-setup website. Usually 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1. There should be a tab where you can manage your Wireless-settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Recover the password**

- Check the sticker on the back of your router if there's a password on it.
- Under a Windows client that connected to the network: click "Start", select Run... And type: "ncpa.cpl". In the windows that appears, Right-click with your mouse on the wireless interface and select "Status...". In the next window, click "Wireless properties" and finally click the checkbox "Show characters".
- Under an OSX client that connected to the network: start the Keychain manager and search for your wifi network name. Double click on the item and select "Show password"
- Log on to your router (assuming you do remember or have that password) and check the wireless password under the wireless settings menu.

**Reset password**

- Log on to your router (assuming you do remember or have that password) and reset the password there. This retains all other settings on your routers.
- Reset your router. This is often achieved by using a sharp pencil or bend paperclip to push inside a small hole at the back or underside of the router. This resets *all of your router settings* to a factory default. Check your router manual for more info.