# How to retrieve the wireless password from a DIR-651 without resetting it?

Tags: wireless-router

I need to grab the wireless password from my DIR-651 router and put in my phone.  I set the router up several months ago and haven't used wireless since.

I have access to the DIR-651 admin page via wired connection, but I am not finding where the wireless passwords are located.  I've looked all over the Manual Wireless setup page.  There is a "pre shared" key at the bottom, but even that is obscured (dots).

Comment: Do you have any systems that are connected to the router? Might be easier to yank the password from there.

Comment: Also see [my answer to this question](http://superuser.com/questions/828329/i-forgot-my-passwork-for-wireless-how-do-i-recover-or-change-it-for-a-westell-r)